# How to combine a negative and positive regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I think it's possible to define a single RegExp string that will check two things - whether the user is NOT trying to enter a post office box and whether the user is using only valid characters.  The two separate RegExp are as follows:

PO BOX Validation :

```
^((?!^.*(\b[Pp]([Oo0][Ss][Tt])?\.*\s*[Oo0]([Ff][Ff]([Ii][Cc][Ee])?)?\.*\s*([Bb][Oo0][Xx])\d*\s*\b.*)).)*$
```

User Can enter these Char Only:

```
^[a-z|A-Z|0-9 _&'/#]*$
```

When I try to simply concatenate the two regex's together with a vertical 'OR' character '|', it doesn't achieve the desired result.  Is this even possible?  Can a single regex achieve both validations?

Comment: What's the desired result? Using `|` is a logical OR, maybe you want an exclusive OR? Also are you separating with with parentheses: `(regexp1)|(regexp2)`?

Comment: Thanks. What is the syntax for that?

Comment: @Brad Somehow the regex was changed so that it would match "Post Office". It appeared at your edit, so I've reverted it.

Comment: @4castle That would have been an edit by the author then, before I edited the formatting only.  (The author of the post can change it quickly without it showing up in edit history.)  If you look at my edit, you'll see I just fixed formatting.  http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38297083/revisions  You should actually revert your edit now, since you have actually changed okorng's intent (even if okorng changed their mind since you last saw it).  What a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use your own regexps to combine, you should notice that the first regex is actually a pattern with a kind of a poorly formed tempered greedy token.

It seems you wanted something like

```
/^(?!.*\b[Pp]([Oo0][Ss][Tt])?\.*\s*[Oo0]([Ff][Ff]([Ii][Cc][Ee])?)?\.*\s*([Bb][Oo0][Xx])\d*\s*\b)[a-zA-Z0-9 _&'\/#]*$/
                                                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mJ6dS9/2)

Note that `[a-z|A-Z|0-9 _&'/#]` should not contain `|`, as they are treated as literal pipe symbols while you most probably meant to use them as OR operators. They are OR operators inside parentheses, but not inside a character class.

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*\b[Pp]([Oo0][Ss][Tt])?\.*\s*[Oo0]([Ff][Ff]([Ii][Cc][Ee])?)?\.*\s*([Bb][Oo0][Xx])\d*\s*\b)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if the pattern inside it is matched
- `[a-zA-Z0-9 _&'/#]*` - zero or more allowed chars
- `$` - end of string.

Since `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` = `\w`, you can write the same as

```
/^(?!.*\b[Pp]([Oo0][Ss][Tt])?\.*\s*[Oo0]([Ff][Ff]([Ii][Cc][Ee])?)?\.*\s*([Bb][Oo0][Xx])\d*\s*\b)[\w &'\/#]*$/
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give this a try.

Comment: Awesome!  Your above solution appears to have worked.  It prevents user from trying to insert a postal box and prevents the invalid chars!  Thank you for the help.

Comment: You might want to use case-insensitve mode. I don't think it will optimize too much other than the time to parse the regex itself, but it will be much more readable.